# Object reuse - mutating same object - in Flink operators

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I was reading the doc [here](https://dzone.com/articles/four-ways-to-optimize-your-flink-applications), which gives a use case to reuse the object as given below:

```java
stream
    .apply(new WindowFunction<WikipediaEditEvent, Tuple2<String, Long>, String, TimeWindow>() {
        // Create an instance that we will reuse on every call
        private Tuple2<String, Long> result = new Tuple<>();
    
        @Override
        public void apply(String userName, TimeWindow timeWindow, Iterable<WikipediaEditEvent> iterable, Collector<Tuple2<String, Long>> collector) throws Exception {
            long changesCount = ...
            
            // Set fields on an existing object instead of creating a new one
            result.f0 = userName;
            // Auto-boxing!! A new Long value may be created
            result.f1 = changesCount;
            
            // Reuse the same Tuple2 object
            collector.collect(result);
        }
    }
```

So every time instead of creating a new Tuple, it seems to be able to use the same Tuple by using its mutable nature in order to decrease the pressure on GC. Would it be applicable in all operators, where we can mutate and pass the same object in the pipeline via `collector.collect(...)` call?

By using that idea, I wonder in what places I can make such an optimization without breaking the code or introducing sneaky bugs. Again as an example a KeySelector which returns a Tuple taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295777/how-to-support-multiple-keyby-in-flink) answer given below:

```java
KeyedStream<Employee, Tuple2<String, String>> employeesKeyedByCountryndEmployer = 
  streamEmployee.keyBy(
    new KeySelector<Employee, Tuple2<String, String>>() {

      @Override
      public Tuple2<String, String> getKey(Employee value) throws Exception {
        return Tuple2.of(value.getCountry(), value.getEmployer());
      }
    }
  );
```

I wonder if that case, can I reuse the same Tuple by mutating it with different inputs as below. Of course in all cases I assume parallelism is more than 1, probably much higher in a real use case.

```java
KeyedStream<Employee, Tuple2<String, String>> employeesKeyedByCountryndEmployer = 
  streamEmployee.keyBy(
    new KeySelector<Employee, Tuple2<String, String>>() {
      
      Tuple2<String, String> tuple = new Tuple2<>();

      @Override
      public Tuple2<String, String> getKey(Employee value) throws Exception {
        tuple.f0 = value.getCountry();
        tuple.f1 = value.value.getEmployer();
        return tuple;
      }
    }
  );
```

I do not know, if Flink copies objects between stages in the pipeline, so I wonder if it's safe to do such an optimization. I read about `enableObjectReuse()` configuration in the docs, though I am not sure if I really understood it. Actually, it may be a bit Flink internals, though could not understand when Flink does what to manage data/object/records in the pipeline. May be I should make this clear first?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sort of reuse in a `KeySelector` is **not** safe. `keyBy` is not an operator, and the usual rules about object reuse in operator chains (which I covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66596638/flink-rule-of-using-object-reuse-mode)) do not apply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer David. If I am not misinterpreting on page https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/operators/overview/ `keyBy` is listed under operators. So all transformations are not operators, but they are just methods on DataStream?

Comment: I'd say the classification in the docs is misleading. keyBy is not a transformation or an operator. It's a declarative description of how two operators are connected (similar in some respects to the role played by rebalance). But keyBy plays a very unique role, given how keys relate to key groups and keyed state.

Answer (score 0):

See Dave Anderson's answer to [Flink, rule of using 'object reuse mode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66596638/flink-rule-of-using-object-reuse-mode)

Basically you can't remember input object references across function calls or
modify input objects. So in your situation above with the `KeySelector`, you're modifying an object that you created, not an input object.

Comment: Are you referring the case object reuse mode is ON?

Comment: Object reuse mode does not apply to key selectors, which cannot safely reuse output objects. I'm pretty sure this will cause weird problems and errors with the HashMapStateBackend.