# Is it safe to modify inputs in flink aggregation?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is it safe to modify input objects in flink aggregation function? Sample code:

```
class Acc {
    int sum = 0;
    int max = 0;
}
public class MyAggFunc implements AggregateFunction<Integer, Acc, Acc> {
    @Override
    public Acc createAccumulator() {
        return new Acc();
    }

    @Override
    public Acc add(Integer value, Acc accumulator) {
        accumulator.sum += value;
        accumulator.max = Math.max(accumulator.max, value);
        return accumulator
    }

    @Override
    public Acc getResult(Acc accumulator) {
        return accumulator
    }

    @Override
    public Acc merge(Acc a, Acc b) {
        a.max = Math.max(a.max, b.max);
        a.sum += b.sum;
        return a;
    }
}
```

In add() and merge() I modify input accumulator and return it to avoid creating new objects in each call. Is it safe?

Answer (score 0):

<s>The way you are doing it yes, it is in fact one of the examples in the docs: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/#aggregatefunction</s>

If you were concerned about the object reuse optimization, these are some guidelines [Flink, rule of using 'object reuse mode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66596638/flink-rule-of-using-object-reuse-mode)

Comment: the official example from your link actually creates new tuples in `add()` and `merge()` and doesn't modify inputs.

Comment: You're right. The object reuse link that I pasted still applies. Our of curiosity, any reason to not create defensive copies?

Comment: in sample code the accumulator is small and simple so creating copies is ok. but in practice when accumulator have many fields and nested objects, deep object copy has more time/memory overhead.